How can I close the dropdown programmatically on button click?
I have the below Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu of labeled checkboxes, with data-bs-auto-close="outside", so that the menu closes on outside click.
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="filter">
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="filter">
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group px-1 mt-2 w-100">
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="apply btn btn-sm btn-success">Apply</button>
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-success">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I want the menu to close when any of the buttons "Apply" and "Reset" is clicked. For this purpose, I have the function below:


function closeFilter() {
  let dropDown = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
  let dropDownButton = dropDown.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropDownButton.style.border = '1px solid red';
  dropDownButton.dropdown('toggle');
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="filter">
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="filter">
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group px-1 mt-2 w-100">
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="apply btn btn-sm btn-success">Apply</button>
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-success">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



However, the above function throws the error:
dropDownButton.dropdown is not a function

Where is my mistake?

You need to get the instance of the specific dropdown. You can use bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance(element) for this.


function closeFilter() {
  let dropDown = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
  let dropDownButton = dropDown.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropDownButton.style.border = '1px solid red';

  bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance(dropDownButton).toggle();
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="filter">
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="filter">
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group px-1 mt-2 w-100">
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="apply btn btn-sm btn-success">Apply</button>
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-success">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




To do this you will have to explictly define the dropDownButton element as a Bootstrap dropdown
and after you will be able to use the toggle method on this
  const dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropDownButton);
  dropdown.toggle();



function closeFilter() {
  let dropDown = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
  let dropDownButton = dropDown.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropDownButton.style.border = '1px solid red';
  const dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropDownButton);
  dropdown.toggle();
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="filter">
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="px-1">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="filter">
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group px-1 mt-2 w-100">
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="apply btn btn-sm btn-success">Apply</button>
      <button onclick="closeFilter()" type="button" class="reset btn btn-sm btn-success">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



